# Code repetitiveness when writing custom extensions

Tags: swift

I pretty often encounter situation like this:

```
 public extension CountableRange {
     func advanced(by n: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        let lowerBound = self.lowerBound.advanced(by: n)
        let upperBound = self.upperBound.advanced(by: n)
        return .init(uncheckedBounds: (lowerBound, upperBound))
    }
    
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        lhs.advanced(by: rhs)
    }
    
    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        lhs.advanced(by: -rhs)
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------

public extension CountableClosedRange {
    func advanced(by n: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        let lowerBound = self.lowerBound.advanced(by: n)
        let upperBound = self.upperBound.advanced(by: n)
        return .init(uncheckedBounds: (lowerBound, upperBound))
    }
    
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        lhs.advanced(by: rhs)
    }
    
    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        lhs.advanced(by: -rhs)
    }
}
```

Absolutely identical two pieces of code. Is there any way to deal with it?
If `CountableRange` and `CountableClosedRange` have conformed to some common protocol `BasicRange` I could just write one extension for that `BasicRange` protocol. But often it's not the case.

Comment: Maybe with Protocol Extension and their default implementation https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID521 and then, just doing `extension CountableRange: ThatCustomProtocol {}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use protocol default implementations to shared add functionality to several built-in types.

You simply need to declare a protocol and extend it with default implementations for the desired functions, then make the built-in types you want to have this functionality conform to the protocol and they'll get the default implementations for free.

```
public protocol BasicRange: RangeExpression where Bound: Strideable {
    var lowerBound: Bound { get }
    var upperBound: Bound { get }
    init(uncheckedBounds bounds: (lower: Bound, upper: Bound))
    func advanced(by n: Bound.Stride) -> Self
    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self
    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self
}

public extension BasicRange {
    func advanced(by n: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        let lowerBound = self.lowerBound.advanced(by: n)
        let upperBound = self.upperBound.advanced(by: n)
        return .init(uncheckedBounds: (lowerBound, upperBound))
    }

    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        lhs.advanced(by: rhs)
    }

    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        lhs.advanced(by: -rhs)
    }
}

extension CountableRange: BasicRange {}
extension CountableClosedRange: BasicRange {}

CountableRange(uncheckedBounds: (1,5)).advanced(by: 1)
CountableClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (1,5)).advanced(by: 1)
```

Comment: Lines "func advanced...", "static func +...", "static func -" in protocol BasicRange probably (I'm not sure) are not necessary, because they are in extension to this protocol. Looks like an unnecessary duplication.

Comment: @Roman there is an important distinction between declaring a function in the protocol declaration and then adding a default implementation to it in an extension or not including the function in the protocol declaration and just adding it in an extension. If you don't include the function in the protocol declaration, conforming types won't be able to override the default implementation when you access the types as the protocol.